# Can't generate a StockID above 10

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is the code that tries to grab the largest StockID from the database (Access database) , but my problem is that it generates StockID's up to "S10", after this it simply doesn't increment any further. This is the subroutine that generates the StockID:

```
Sub generate_Stock_ID()

        Dim Stock_start As String = "S"

        Dim Stock_Gen As String = "SELECT MAX(StockID) FROM tblStock WHERE StockID LIKE '" & Stock_start & "%%%' "
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(Stock_Gen, conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "StockID")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("StockID")

        Dim count As Integer = ds.Tables("StockID").Rows.Count

        If ds.Tables("StockID").rows.count = 0 Then
            StockID = "S1"
        Else
            StockID = ds.Tables("StockID").Rows(0).Item(0)
            StockID = StockID.Substring(1, (StockID.Length - 1))
            StockID = Stock_start & (StockID + 1)
        End If

    End Sub
```

[Screenshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqidp.png)

Note* there are multiple ID's for various other subroutines which all share the same incrementation issue, so if i fix this i fix the other ones too. So at the moment i think my problem lies in the syntax of my SQL statement, but im open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run it line-by-line in the debugger to make sure you're getting the right results back?

Comment: yes, it returns S10, what i gathered from line by line, is that it identifies S9 as the largest record in the database, then does my formating where it adds one to the number and produces S10, but if i were to run it after this, it will still find S9 as the largest in the database.

Comment: And why do you think it chooses `S9` over `S10`?

Comment: You should make this columns an `int`-column and prepend `S` where you display it. Otherwise you need to cast the substring in the database to int to be able to use MAX or ORDER BY in a numerical way.

Comment: Presumably because it ignored the 0 in S10 and see's it as S1, meaning S9 would be seen as larger leading to my conclusion that the syntax of my selection is wrong, not sure though

Comment: @TimSchmelter the database has various other ID's in the same column  wouldnt this just confuse the current structure of the database.

Comment: @user3771226: i don't know which kind of ID's are stored in that column. If they all have  `S` at the beginning you could first remove that, then add the a new `int` column with this value casted to `int`. Finally you can delete the old column and rename the new to the old.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Its in the screenshot i posted, they dont all start with S, so it simply removing that convention would void the other ID's

Comment: @user3771226: are that all records? Then you can update them manually. I would use an `int` column for this. Maybe you need another column for this `CA1` if it's needed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter would kinda defeat the purpose of automation if i did it manually, at the momment this is just some alpha testing, i could technically have hundreds of records maybe thousands when i use this system. Manual may not be viable.

Comment: @user3771226: my advice is to change the type of the column or (easier) to add another column which is of type `int`. Then use that column for this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of this issue that `StockID` is a STRING and 'S1'>'S10' so for all StockId > 10 you get max = 'S1'.

As a fast fix try to change `MAX(StockID)` to:

```
SELECT 'S'+CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(StockID,2,100) as int)) as varchar(100))
```

For ACCESS DB try to use:

```
 SELECT "S" & cstr(MAX(CINT(MID(StockID,2,100))))
```

Comment: "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)" - Error produced, any ideas?

Comment: @user3771226: This was a MSSQL syntax. I added Access command.

Comment: Awww yiss, i think it works, i will spend a while trying to figure out this code but it works for now :p

Answer (score 1):

Don't treat an `Integer` as `String`. Otherwese `MAX` or `ORDER BY` will use lexicographical instead of numerical order which means that `S11` is "lower" than `S2`.

So you should make this column an `int`-column and prepend `S` only where you display it. Then `MAX(StockID)` returns an `Integer`, you just have to cast it and add 1:

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Connection-String")
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Stock_Gen, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim stockIDObj As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If stockIDObj IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim maxStockId As Int32 = DirectCast(stockIDObj, Int32)
            maxStockId += 1
            ' ...... '
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

You should also change `OPTION STRICT` to `ON`. Then this would never compile since the same variable cannot be used for an `Object`, `String` and `Integer` which is very good since it prevents errors.

If you want to keep it as string you have to cast the substring always in the database which is less readable and less efficient. I also don't know how to do it in access.

If you want to change the type of column in an already populated table you should first add a new column with a similar name which is of type `int`. If all  have  `S` at the beginning you could first remove that, then you can update the new column with the casted `int` value. Finally you can delete the old column and rename the new to the old.