# Does number of wildcard characters(specially %) matter in SQL Like Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A question regarding the use of % in T-SQL  [Like](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) statement

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387438/cant-generate-a-stockid-above-10) on SO and was puzzled to see 3 % in a like statement

I initially thought they mean the same , i.e. using

```
select * from Tbl where name like 'Abc%'
```

and

```
select * from Tbl where name like 'Abc%%%'
```

I just need to know if they are different and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No it does not.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms179859.aspx)

See the list of special characters on that site (copying from the link, paragraph "Arguments"):

```
 % Any string of zero or more characters.

 _ (underscore) Any single character.
```

On a side note: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3b45/5) is really neat for testing this kind of small things if you don't have a SQL Server Management Studio available.

EDIT: sry just saw you already linked that page in your question, but the behavior of those wildchard characters actually matches exactly what that page states about their behavior.

Comment: Good enough, I was just looking for a case where they are not equal!